# jQuery next() for divs

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a scroll-able div, and so far I have this:

```
<div id="topBar"> 
    <span>
        <a id='slink' class='trigger' href='#Sports'>Sport</a>
        <a id='elink' class='trigger'  href='#Entertainment'>Entertainment</a >
        <a id='mlink' class='trigger' href='#Military'>Military</a>

        <a id='mocklink' class='trigger' href='#MockUp'>MockUps</a>
        <button>Next</button>
    </span>
</div>
```

ok, so maybe this is a bit simpler, I understand that i wasnt very clear at all last time:

How would I use the button in the above code to get from link to link? eg from sport to entertainment

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need this?

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $('a.trigger:visible').first().fadeOut(500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`.next()` just retrieves the next DOM element, it doesn't scroll to it. Try this:

```
$div = $('.' + x).next().next();
$('body').animate({scrollTop:$div.position().top});
```

Comment: Hi, does the above post make more sense? Matt

Comment: What do you mean by "get from link to link"? You need to elaborate on what you want the end result to be, and on what you have tried so far.

Comment: So, I would like to scroll from sport to entertainment using a but (just like you would in a slideshow). ideally I want to access the next div according to the one i'm currently on by pressing a button

Comment: You keep mentioning divs, but I don't see any divs in your sample code. I'm sorry, but I don't think I can be any more help to you.